# In Laravel 10, I want to use PEST with token auth on api testing

Tags: laravel

Slowly going crazy...

I want to use PEST for laravel API testing - I'm suspecting this is bad.

Tests work fine, until I hit routes that need token auth. This seems impossible using PEST as it keeps getting 404 errors.

Here is my current attempt:

```
use App\Models\Chemical;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Models\User;

uses(RefreshDatabase::class);

test('it retrieves a list of chemicals', function (){
    $chemical = Chemical::factory()->create();

    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $token = $user->createToken('api-token')->plainTextToken;

    $this->getJson('/v1/chemicals', ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson([
            'data' => [
                [
                    'id' => $chemical->id,
                    'name' => $chemical->name,
                    'extra' => $chemical->extra,
                    'cas_number' => $chemical->cas_number,
                ]
            ]
        ]);
});
```

This fails with:

```
ChemicalControllerTest > it retrieves a list of chemicals                    
  Expected response status code [200] but received 404.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.
```

using dd - I see that a valid token does get generated - but it seems to barf.. Weirdly it seems to nuke all seeded users as well..

This curl works fine

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://laravel-api.test/api/v1/chemicals \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer 1|laravel_sanctum_HbPJpzXxpxU2EUqS9wkflt0h9OUPlaMoWQWUYtKseedfe14f'
```

What am I getting wrong? Or should I manually login to get a token and then save it into my code?

I did originally want to have some kind of global function to carry a token so that I didn't have to write boilerplate to create tokens...

Comment: Are you sure about your route ? Because you are receiving a 404 and not a 401.

Comment: confirmed that the route is correct - also added to question sample working curl

Comment: I guess it is a problem with your test environnment or maybe a conflict with another test. Is this the only test running ? I have barely the same test running on my APIs and no problem with it, the only difference is that I am using `$this->withToken($token)->getJson('...')` to add the token.

Comment: ah.. looks like I have to insert "/api" at the start - <facepalm>

Comment: Now is there a nice way of doing a global token for all tests in PEST? so I don't have to type tons of boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

core problem is that PEST didn't read my mind and realise the route starts with '/api'

However a better way to insert the route is to used the route name (assuming you named your route)
Then you get

```
$this->withToken($token)->getJson(route('chemicals.index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your app url to localhost in your phpunit.xml file

`<server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>`

And clear your config cache

`php artisan config:cache`

Comment: nope that is nothing to do with it sorry